# Check if value exist in array even if it is followed by other letters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with multiples values

```
let array = ['value othervalue', 'value2 othervalue2']
```

I want to check :

```
if (array.includes('value')){
    do that
}
```

It return `false` because its not 'value' its 'value othervalue'

**I would like it to return `true` because the word is well existing but accompanied by another!**

What javascript function can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.some` to check whether one of the items includes `'value'`:

```js
let array = ['value othervalue', 'value2 othervalue2']

if(array.some(e => e.includes('value'))){
  console.log('includes')
}
```